# Laravel 7.x DB Transaction auto commit without commit() command

Tags: laravel, transactions, commit, rollback, autocommit

I have a function that uses Query builder to insert a records to database.
I want to use transaction manually.

But the record is inserted to database without calling the `commit()` function.
I don't know why; I want to the inserting function to wait for me until I call the `commit()` function.

In my script are 2 commands:

1. insert into `products` (correct command)
2. insert into `product_categories` (invalid command – I set field `prd_idd` instead of `prd_id`)

In this case I expect command #1 not to insert to the database when #2 failed.

```
public function create($params)
{
    DB::beginTransaction();
    try {
        DB::table('products')->insert($params);
        DB::table('prd_categories')->insert(['prd_idd'=> 1, 'category_id' => 1]);
    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        echo $ex->getMessage();
        DB::rollback();
    }
    die("End");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To run a set of operations within a database `transaction`, you may use the transaction method on the `DB` facade. If an exception is thrown within the transaction `Closure`, the transaction will automatically be rolled back. If the `Closure` executes successfully, the transaction will automatically be committed. You don't need to worry about manually rolling back or committing while using the `transaction` method:

```
DB::transaction(function () {
    DB::table('product')->insert(...);
    DB::table('prd_categories')->insert(...);
});
```

Comment: Hi Hirapara,
As you suggested i put them intro the block:.

        $this->params = $params;
        DB::transaction(function () {
            DB::table('products')->insert($this->params);
            DB::table('prd_categories')->insert(['prd_idd'=> 1, 'category_id' => 1]);
        });
And this is the result:
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'prd_idd' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `prd_categories` (`prd_idd`, `category_id`) values (1, 1))
but it created new record for product by command #1. it's should be auto rollback, but not, i don't know why?